# How would I add products from an XML feed from sage?

Tags: magento-1.8, mysql, php-5.4, xml

We are creating a website and we are using products from sage. We have a script in PHP that pulls the XML feed for the products we want on sage. How would I go about getting that into Magento?

I just started with web programming and Magento and have been watching tutorials. I am just not sure where to start with all of this. I am thinking that creating a database using PHPmyAdmin would be the best way to go? Also I would need to update the product list daily as new items get added and taken off of sage.

Comment: What does sage means?

Comment: @mbalparda: Sage is an ERP system built by the company with the same name.

Comment: @dom: this is a very broad question and you could write a whole book about that. Normally StackExchange is more about precise, narrow-scoped questions. I'm afraid it will get closed.

Comment: Should I narrow it down to how to add many products to magento at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to get many products into Magento at once. Here is a topic discussing the options: [What is the most common process for importing products?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43/what-is-the-most-common-process-for-importing-products)

I use Magmi, and it is wonderful. But I recommend not downloading the original Magmi from SourceForge. Instead, use the more user-friendly version here: http://understandinge.com/

It takes work to get it setup. But it works many times faster than Magento's built-in product importer. If you are importing thousands of products, it might take Magento all night. Magmi takes minutes.

Magmi can also automatically update the products. For example, my supplier's website publishes a CSV file with changed stock levels (quantities). Magmi, running on my site, checks the supplier's CSV file every day and then updates my stock levels to match the suppliers.

I am not familiar with Sage. But basically, if you can get it to output a CSV file, you can use Magmi to check it as often as you want and update your site.

Comment: Thank you I am looking into Magmi now and it seems like that may be a viable solution for me.

Comment: That depends, for initial loads Magmi is very good (generally) - however for data maintenance you need to perform reindexes. This is fine if you have a few thousand products but if you have 10s to 100s thousands it effectively doens't work with CE. Then you need other tools - so it depends on the level.